# color codes in textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors, tags

Is it possible to color the user entering code (inside a textarea) using jquery.

Specific texts like `<h1>`, `<b>` etc should be colored or highlighted.

this helps to distinguish the opening closing tags.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.
Text blocks in `<textarea>` elements cannot be formatted.

You need to use a ContentEditable element.
Try [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/).

Comment: yes i want like CodeMirror ! but it uses huge resources. you really understood my question !

Comment: @Aakash: Try http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea&sess=331315502f818b070fbd7873da9e0844

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will only be able to edit the styles of elements that can be styled using CSS. It is not possible to edit colours inside an input element in this way.

You might want to check out

SyntaxHighlighter

http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter

Comment: You're right - 
Sorry I should have given this more thought. SyntaxHighlighter cannot be used to edit code.