# How to change the background color to perticular word inside a h:inputTextarea

Tags: jsf

I made a from with input text area, and the value will come from database.
value is some thing like : A 2 year notice has bean applied by mycompany with effect from 12 December 2012.
I want to hilight **12 December 2012** with some different background color.

Note: value will come dinamycally from database.

```
<h:inputTextarea cols="60" rows="5" id="messageId" style="margin-top:3px;"
    value="#{messageBean.textMessage}" />
```

How can i do this? Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `<h:inputTextarea` generates `<textarea`

Its impossible

Take a look at this similar questions:

[Change the Color Of Certain Words In Textarea using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2990170/617373)

And

[color codes in textarea using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063251/617373)

You can use some *WYSIWYG text editor*

Like this one used in [Primefaes Editor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf)

Or just integrate some third party js WYSIWYG text editor , like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

---

You also can strip all the toolbars/buttons from the editor , so it will eventually look like almost like a `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

No it is impossible. 
But you can do a trick. 
You can make your `<h:inputTextarea` component transparent by using the css property `background:transparent;`. Then use another colored div and place it behind the word you want to highlight. Sometimes you may need to add `display:inline-block;`  to your highlighter div if JSF doesn't render the div with the width you give. A negative `z-index` may also be needed.